# Why didn't LO7898 fly near the North Pole?

Tags: flight-path, flightradar24

I've seen [LO7898's route from Seoul to Warsaw on flightradar24](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/sp-lrh#2c86a934). Instead of flying the shortest route (over Mongolia, Russia and near the North Pole) it flew as if Earth was a cylinder: over China, Kazakhstan and so on, simply westwards as if Earth was cylindric. It looked to me as if they wanted to avoid flying over Russia, but why would they want that? Did Mongolia and/or Russia forbid LOT (Polish Airlines) to fly over their soil, and why?

[image: flightradar24 screenshot of route]

Comment: Why the many downvotes? Perhaps it would still be a shorter route if the plane went around Russia north of it, close to the North Pole, not south.

Answer (score 4):

Since you seem not to be aware, the Russian airspace is closed to LOT  and others because of the war in Ukraine.

Because of the war, EU countries (and a few more) closed their airspace to Russian airlines.

As a tit for tat, Russia closed its airspace to airlines of those countries.

This includes Poland, and thus, LOT.

https://www.euronews.com/travel/2022/02/27/russia-closes-airspace-to-planes-from-several-eu-countries

https://www.airport-technology.com/news/russia-shuts-airspace/

https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-60539303